# How to change the hierarchy display style of a XtraTreeView?

Tags: devexpress, appearance

I have an XtraTreeView control that I've upgraded from 9.2 to 10.2. The hierarchy used to be displayed in the 'classic way' - ie. `+` to expand, `-` to collapse, like in this picture: http://documentation.devexpress.com/HelpResource.ashx?help=WindowsForms&document=img1103.jpg

However, in 10.2, they've changed it so the + has been replaced by `>` (like the play button on a remote) to expand and `v` to collapse. Any way to revert it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the TreeList's LookAndFeel property to resolve this problem.  For example:

```
LookAndFeel.UseDefaultLookAndFeel  = false;
LookAndFeel.SkinName  = "Caramel";
```

Comment: So this is related to the LookAndFeel then. Now onto my other question, hehe :-p